# Openfeint game accept/decline

Tags: iphone, openfeint

I am having a multi slot openfeint game. Before starting a game, one player should issue the challenge and the othe player should accept or decline the challenge. My issue is, at some points of time, when I receive a challenge, I am not able to either accept or decline, and the game will stuck in Openfeint server.

does anyone knows if this is a bug in Openfeint?

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically this problem happens when you exceed 20 game slots no matter how much you set the maximum number of OF slots. I dont know why OF guys are not mentioning it anywhere??